# Curvature line equation

Tags: differential-geometry

while reviewing the book on differential geometry by Manfredo do Carmo, I came across the equation of lines of curvature. Do Carmo roughly states the following: A connected regular curve $C$ in a coordinate neighborhood $x$ is a line of curvature if, and only if for any parametrization $\alpha(t) = x(u(t), v(t))$, $t \in I$, of $C$, the following equation is satisfied: $$ N(u,v)(v^{\prime})^{2} + M(u,v) u^{\prime} v^{\prime} + L(u,v) (u^{\prime})^{2} = 0,$$
where $N(u,v)= gF - fG, M(u,v)= gE - eG, N(u,v)= fE - eF$, and $E,F,G$ are coefficients of the first fundamental form, and $e,f,g$ are coefficients of the second fundamental form.

My questions are as follows:

1. If I solve the equation, do I find "directions" in the coordinate plane where, whenever I take derivatives of curves in those directions, their tangent vectors at the derived point are the greatest or smallest? (As, for example, in the case of surfaces of revolution, where I would have $x(u_{0},v)$ or $x(u,v_{0})$).
2. If I find the points $(u_{0},v_{0})$ where the functions $N=M=L=0$, am I finding umbilical points? If not, what do I find through this process?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Directions ( in Euler relation ) associated  with max/min normal curvatures.

Comment: Hi @Narasimham. I think the same in the first question, but, in the second question?

Comment: Yes, $\mathrm{II} = c\mathrm I$ iff the shape operator is $c$ times the identity map.

Comment: Hi, @TedShifrin I don't understand your answer, can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

No, we have proportionality of coefficients in the two fundamental forms. We have in the alternate notation of normal curvature. Let

$$\kappa_n=\frac{Ldu^2+2Mdudv+Ndv^2}{Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2}$$

$$\frac{E}{L}=\frac{F}{M}=\frac{G}{N} = \mu, \text{a constant that need not be necessarily positive.}$$

It can be shown  for surface $r$
$$N_1= -\mu \cdot r $$

Differentiate w.r.t $v$ and $u$ and subtracting,

$$ N_{12}= N_{21}, ~\mu_1r_2=\mu_2 r_1;$$
since

$$ r_1 \text{ is not parallel to } r_2,  \mu s \text { are constant making }$$

$$ \mu_1=0,~\mu_2=0 $$

If constant $\mu$  is non-zero

$$r_1=-N_1/\mu,  \text{ it  integrates to } r=-N_1/\mu+r_0$$

with  $r_o$ as a  constant of integration

$$ (r-r_o)^2 =\frac{N^2}{\mu^2}~=\frac{1}{\mu^2}~$$
Thus $r$ locus is a *sphere* of arbitrary position in $ \mathbb {R^3}$.

If $\mu$  in particular is zero, $N_1=N_2=0,$ the $N$ vector itself  is constant and the surface is a *plane* of arbitrary rotation and displacement.

The normal curvature is independent of curvature ratios $(du,dv), $ same value holding good for all directions, so all such points are *umbilics* on the surface.